# styling elements of a plugin

Tags: css

[Live site.](http://parlourdc.com/wp/get-in-touch)

I'm trying to style the content currently in black under the Upcoming Events heading. I've tried every combination of `.vevent-item odd event-1 .description .event-time .event-label` I thought might work to no avail. Any ideas?

It should match my other `<p>` content.

Comment: Does the plugin include a stylesheet? Where are you trying to add the styles?

Comment: I've tried to add it to both my regular style.cc and the plugin stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, just adding the following code into the `<head>` style tag does the job.

```
#main div.content div.event-item {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to style the following parts: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLYec.png

Why not add a new class to those div's? For example:

```
<div class="event-time foo">...</div>
<div class="foo">...</div>
```

And in your .css file:

```
.foo {
  background-color: red;  
}
```